# SkyBox does not move with camera

Tags: android, opengl-es

In My OpenGL application I have created a SkyBox which works great if I render it from the origin. I render it with the PVMatrix (ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix [Camera]) and as I said if I render it from the origin all works great. But if I move the camera to let's say (0,6,-8) it does not work and the SkyBox is rendered as normal cube.

I thought that it is enought to create a ModelMatrix for the SkyBox and set the position in it to the position of the camera but this does not help. Of course I render the SkyBox with the new MVPMatrix now. Do you have any ideas why that does not work and what can I do to get it work?

Comment: In general translating the skybox to the camera should work out. Have you checked if you move it to the correct position? Alternatively, one can use instead of the original view matrix only the rotational part of it (set the fourth column/fourth row to [0,0,0,1]).

Comment: I found my mistake. I moved my camera to z=-8 and my SkyBox also to z=-8 but I have to move it to z=8 so I multiplied with -1. Now it works great but this let's me think about the axes in my application. For objects my positive z axis points out of the screen and for the camera the negative z axis? That can't be right or have I missed something?

Comment: I will explain this in an answer. Got to much text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general translating the skybox to the camera should work out. Have you checked if you move it to the correct position?

One of the most common failures is that you move the camera in the same direction as your object, which results in moving the object twice away in the wrong direction. To explain this, let's have a look on the different coordinate systems:

Each model is defined in it's own model space. Lets call this space M. Using the model matrix (m), we are able to transform from model space to world space (W).

```
M ---m---> W
```

Now we have a second object in our scene, the camera, with its view space V and cameras model matrix c. Again we can transform

```
V ---c---> W
```

But since we need everything in view space instead of getting the camera to world space, we have to invert this transformation such that

```
W ---v---> V
```

In general this is given by `v = c^-1`, which is the view-matrix one specifies in the application. From knowing this, it should be quite clear why you have to move your object by z=-8 when your view-matrix contains a translation to z=8 (since T(8) = T(-8)^-1). For more details have a look at [this presentation](https://lva.cg.tuwien.ac.at/ecg/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=revisioncourse_2014.pdf) (starting from slide 6)